# parfor use in matlab with a cellarray

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I need your help. Why the following is not working:

```
parfor n = 1:size(train_name, 1) 


    FV_train{n} = Fisher(CF_train{n}, 47);
    parfor_progress;



end
```

CF_train holds n*512x512 images which should be processed parllel and stored in the cell arrayFV_train which I already initialized.
On my other routines this works if I call my function Fisher with imread.

[image]

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Are you getting an error?  If so, put it in your questions.  How are you initializing FV_train?

Comment: I get the error that the function vl_gmm could not been opened, but when I use only for it works. FV_train = cell(size(train_name, 1), 1);

Comment: Are you using a local profile, or a distributed server?  It sounds like your workers don't all have access to the same files, and that you may need to use [pctRunOnAll](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/pctrunonall.html) to set the paths appropriately.

Comment: I am using a local profile